# Algebraic proof of pure transcendence and unirational varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Using the following definition:

> A variety is said to be unirational whenever there is a dominant rational map $\phi: \mathbb{P}^n\dashrightarrow X$

I was trying to prove that $X$ being uniration is equivalent to there existing a generically finite morphism from $Y\rightarrow X$ for some rational $Y$. The proof I was able to find in some sources stated that if the we have a dominant morphism $Z\rightarrow X$ for a quasi-projective variety $Z$ and if the dimension of the fiber of the generic point of $X$ is non-zero, we can find a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$ which intersects $Z$ and this induces a rational map from the hyperplane to $X$ is dense and hence we bring down the dimension of the fiber. Then we can repeat this process and to get our desired result.

I am unable to understand why such a hyperplane should exist? If it deos, the algorithm works and there is no problem at all.

I was trying to work on an alternate proof for this I would need the following result: if $k\subset K$ are fields such that $k\subset K\subset k(x_1,...,x_n)$. Then, if $K$ is algebraically closed in $k(x_1,...,x_n)$, $K$ is a purely transcedental over $k$. Is this result true. If so, is there any straight forward way to prove it?

Comment: It's not clear to me how all of these pieces fit together in the argument. Is $Z$ some quasi-projective subvariety of $\mathbb P^n$? And are we asking that it intersect the hyperplane in some special way? Because you can always find a hyperplane intersecting a given subvariety in some way or another; that requires no conditions whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, Z is a quasi-projective subvariety of $P^n$. Sure, a hyperplane will definitely intersect a subvariety. But, why should that Induce a dominant rational map from the hyperplane to $X$? Most of the proof I found seem to suggest you can find a such a hyperplane.

Comment: Ah OK, then you might want to edit your question; the phrase "the resulting rational map" suggests that you understand the construction of the rational map. In particular you might want to just link to one of the proofs you've been looking at, because as written I cannot see what map is implied.

Comment: I have made the edit. Here is one of the sources where I saw this idea being used :http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/07-08/Spring/18.726/l_7.pdf

Comment: Ah, OK, now I see. He's saying that if you have a dominant rational map $\mathbb P^n \dashrightarrow X$ but $\dim X < n$, then you can find some hyperplane in $\mathbb P^n$ on which the restriction of the map is still dominant. If $\dim X < n-1$, you just repeat until the dimensions match up. I don't have a precise argument in mind just yet, but it seems geometrically "obvious," and might just require a bit of playing around with the dimension of fibers theorem.

Comment: The assertion about transcendental extensions is Lüroth's Theorem in the case $n=1$, but it is not true for $n>1$.

Comment: @HagenKnaf Could you give a me some counterexample for the $n>1$ case?

Comment: Google Lüroth's Theorem/Problem. See e.g. https://ajwilson.co.uk/files/maths/luroth-problem.pdf.